# Physics behind a blue "firenado"

Tags: vortex, combustion

In the NYTimes video [Harnessing the Firenado](http://www.nytimes.com/video/science/100000004614262/harnessing-the-firenado.html), a rotating yellow sooty flame is suddenly transformed into a clean blue rotating flame.

What is the physics behind this transformation? What is it about the new flow pattern that allows the combusting mixture to be maintained sufficiently long that the combustion is complete, or to inhibit the formation of carbon soot particles?

NYTimes: [New Form of Fire, Inspired by Bourbon, Might Help With Oil Spills](http://www.nytimes.com/2016/08/29/science/firenado-fire-whirl.html).

YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zlYQ5-uDSqs

"[From fire whirls to blue whirls and combustion with reduced pollution](http://www.pnas.org/content/113/34/9457)" Xiao, Gollner and Oran (2016), PNAS 113, (34) 9457-9462, doi: 10.1073/pnas.1605860113

Possibly helpful [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WVeJ2Sieg44)

**note:** the bright yellow in hydrocarbon flames generally comes from thermal radiation by hot soot. In the video the suggestion is that the disappearance of the bright yellow flame indicates there is far less soot produced. It could be possible that soot is produced but it's not hot enough to glow - is there further evidence that the soot production is suppressed?

[image: Firenado NYTimes]

Comment: Isn't the physics described in the PNAS article? Your final question about soot suppression is probably chemistry, not physics.

Comment: @sammygerbil It might very well be in the article - I am traveling and I haven't been successful downloading or opening the article with the internet connection I have. When I get to a better location - if I can read it and the answer is there I'll post an answer myself, but I'm not an expert in fluid dynamics. If you can read the article please feel free to leave an answer! The change in the flame is most likely a physical effect related to confinement time. The difference between a a kerosene lamp and a kerosene-burning rocket engine (for example) isn't chemistry, it's physics.

Comment: @sammygerbil actually a rocket engine is at the crossroads of physics and chemistry - there are no hard distinctions, but in the stackexchange environment we have to sometimes make arbitrary calls on questions that involve both. But I'm pretty sure the answer to this question will be mostly physical aspects of the flame, and how they provide an environment for more complete combustion after the transition. The heat, gravity, and angular momentum work together to provide this environment *somehow* - I'm asking how.

Answer (score 2):

The physics behind the transition from a fire whirl to a blue whirl is the phenomenon called vortex breakdown that occurs in flows where you have both axial and swirling motion. The breakdown is triggered for sufficiently strong swirling motions.

With respect to blue whirls, you can find swirl-controlled experimental results in Coenen et al. (2019) [Observed dependence of characteristics of liquid-pool fires on swirl magnitude](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.combustflame.2019.03.032) (also in [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.06567)).

> Abstract:
>
> One dozen vertically oriented thin rectangular vanes, 62 cm tall and 15.2 cm wide, were placed 27 cm from the center of heptane and ethanol pool fires in continuously fed, floor-flush pans 3.2 cm and 5.1 cm in diameter in the laboratory. The vanes were all oriented at the same fixed angles from the radial direction, for 9 different angles, ranging from 0∘ to 85∘, thereby imparting 9 different levels of circulation to the air entrained by each pool fire. The different swirl levels were observed to engender dramatically different pool-fire structures. Moderate swirl suppresses the global puffing instability, replacing it by a global helical instability that generates a tall fire whirl, the height of which increases with increasing circulation. Except for the largest heptane pool, higher swirl levels produced vortex breakdown, resulting in the emergence of a bubble-like recirculation region with a ring vortex encircling the axis. Measured burning rates increase with increasing swirl levels as a consequence of the associated increasing inflow velocities reducing the thickness of the boundary layer within which combustion occurs right above the liquid surface, eventually forming detached edge flames in the boundary layer that move closer to the axis as the circulation is increased. Still higher circulation reduces the burning rate by decreasing the surface area of the liquid covered by the flame, thereby reducing the height of the fire whirl. Even higher circulation causes edge-flame detachment, resulting in formation of the blue whirl identified in recent literature, often meandering over the surface of the liquid in the present experiments. This sequence of events is documented herein.

[image: Figure 5: Detachment of the flame edge from the rim, lifting of the flame edge, and the formation of a blue whirl, for ethanol with a fuel-pool diameter 2a = 51 mm.]

> Figure 5: Detachment of the flame edge from the rim, lifting of the flame edge, and the formation of a blue whirl, for ethanol with a fuel-pool diameter 2a = 51 mm.

Comment: Welcome! Please provide some context for the links in your answer; see [this guidance](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/384918)

Comment: Thank you for your answer; the paper is quite helpful! I've added a bit to your answer to help address some of the comments and increase the usefulness to future readers, please feel free to adjust or add additional context.